# Javascript, execute function

Tags: javascript, function, function-call

I have next function

```
  var hideAll = function() {
    // code  
    return ///...  
  };
```

And I am using this function like callback in another function.
When I am using it like

```
function (params, hideAll) {}
```

all working well, but when I am using

```
function (params, hideAll() ) {}
```

all not working well!

So my question is, what is difference between `hideAll` and `hideAll()` function executions?

Comment: hideAll is a variable which is reffering to function. and hideAll(); is execution of function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hideAll` - this is a reference to the function
`hideAll()` - this is execution of the function, its result

`function (params, hideAll) {}` is a correct function definition,
whereas `function (params, hideAll() ) {}` is not - you are unable to call another function in function definition.

However you could still write the following valid code:

```
  var hideAll = function() {
    // code  
    return ///...  
  };  

  var functionWithCallback = function(callback){
      callback();
  }
  var closureReferringHideAll = function(){
      hideAll();
  }

  // The following two lines will do exactly the same in current context,
  // i.e. execute hideAll.
  functionWithCallback(hideAll);
  closureReferringHideAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

**hideAll()** is not a function, it is result of execution function.

```
function hideAll(){
    return 0;
}
```

**hideAll()** - number 0

**hideAll** - function

Answer (score 0):

Let's step back for a moment and assume you would call a method `foo`
first like this:

```
foo(params, hideAll() ) {}
```

This uses the *return value* of hideAll as the value

whereas

```
foo(params, hideAll) {}
```

Uses the hideAll function *itself* as the value

However, what you actually tried to do is to *declare* a function like this:

```
function (params, hideAll() ) {}
```

That makes no sense. You can't *declare* a function with anything different from a parameter in the parameter list.

So while both forms are legal for *function invocation* (still with a total different meaning) the latter isn't legal for *function declaration*

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript and in many other languages functions are "first class objects" and this means that you can call/execute a function but you can also store the function in a variable or in an array, or you can pass a function to another function.

Note that I'm not talking about passing the value resulting from calling a function... but the function itself. Consider:

```
function test10(f) {
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++)
        alert(f(i));
}

function square(x) { return x*x*; }
function cube(x) { return x*x*x; }

test10(square);
test10(cube);
```

The last two lines are passing a function (`square` and `cube`) as a parameter to function `test10`.

The `()` syntax tells Javascript that you want to make the call, and can be used not only with function names, but with any expression like variables or array elements... for example:

```
var f_arr = [square, cube];
for (var i=0; i<2; i++)
  alert(f_arr[i](i+42));  // Will call square(42) and cube(43)
```

Actually in Javascript the code

```
function square(x) {
  return x * x;
}
```

is not identical but similar to

```
square = function(x) {
    return x * x;
};
```

so defining a function is indeed close to assigning a variable